# How to integrate app-Level packages into Vue 3 Webcomponents?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, web-component, vue-i18n, primevue

**Kontext**

Vue 3 provides a way to create "Custom-Elements": https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/web-components.html#building-custom-elements-with-vue

The idea as far as I understand it, is to create Custom Elements, that can be used anywhere, as a Web component.
Here (https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/web-components.html#building-custom-elements-with-vue) the developers specifically recommend using custom elements for component libraries.

**Environment/Motivation**

A client has a bigger UI Project that is based on other frameworks. He wants to switch to vue, but doesn't have the resources to completely rewrite/replace everything with a normal vue application. Therefore he wants to replace everything step by step by using webcomponents or more specifically, vue-components (with all the advantages of vue) that are compatible with his project.

**Problem**

The custom elements don't have global vue instance, because you don't mount a custom element, rather you mount a vue application.

However many libraries and packages like i18n, primevue, vuetify, (vuex), ... assume, that they are used in a global instance. At least their documentation requires adding them to the global app instance, otherwise, various features don't work.

**Question**

*How can I use libraries that require a global vue instance to work, in the context of multiple custom elements?*

**Implicit Expectation**

As a developer, I assumed, that major libraries like the ones I mentioned work for custom elements as well. I know that this requires each element to include a small "app instance", which I would guess could lead to performance issues.

For E.g. you create a Website with 100 custom elements with each having an app instance.
If these performance issues I worry about are not essential, then I still could create a classic Webcomponent where I mount a vue app on it. (Following this comment, which I tested and it worked with some adjustments: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-web-component-wrapper/issues/93#issuecomment-909136116)

Comment: I currently creating my own i18n module for vuejs 3. You dont need a global vue instance https://www.npmjs.com/package/vui18n

Comment: Given the age of your package: Did you create that for me? But Humor aside: We currently use: https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/introduction.html Would you say, your package covers all of the features of the mentioned package, or would you say there are some missing? In other words: is your package based on i18n or is it something new?

Comment: it does not cover all. its much smaller, i made it for fun. you can translate, switch langauge, getlanguages, setlanguage, set default language, persist state in localstorage or cookie. i add some new features too.